# Getting a 400 Bad Request in Postman with Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, postman, laravel-passport

I am using Laragon for my project. I have setup passport and a controller as it is indicated in the Laravel docs but im not able to get a token response, just a 400 bad request.

My config is as follows:

[image: env]

[image: user.php]

[image: AuthServiceProvider.php]

[image: auth.php]

[image: AuthController.php]

[image: api.php]

[image: postman]

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Pasting code is more helpful than screenshots in the future. :-)

Comment: Please add all information in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The login route should be in `web.php` instead of `api.php`

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your answer, but isnt that just a best practice?

Comment: The general idea is `web.php` is for pages seen by the user (such as in their browser) and `api.php` is for SPA api calls or for creating third-party API's.

Comment: Then it was correct to have the route in api.php, frontend will be built using react.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing, such that others can learn from it